# EJB 3 Many-to-many with selection criteria

Tags: java, many-to-many, ejb-3.0

I wonder if this is possible at all. I haven't found any examples on how to do it.

My primary entity is a registrant. A registrant can have many interest and an interest can be assigned to many registrants. A classical many-to-many situation.

It's modelled in my database with a classical join table (it contains a unique id but otherwise just a reg_id and interest_id). This works superbly.

I have just defined this on the registrant:

```
 @JoinTable(name = "registrant_interest", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "registrant_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},   
inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "interest_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@ManyToMany
private Collection<Interest> interestCollection;
```

Now my problem. When a registrant log into the system he choses a conference. So only a certain number of interests should be in the collection...the interests for the chosen conference.

But with the approach i've chosen i get all interest from all conferences that the registrant has ever registered for.

Is it possible to have a

'where conference_id = ?' from the interest side in this construction or do I have to use a view instead?

best regards and thanks for any help

Kim

Comment: you can simple use HQL with your specific criteria , share the code you are using to retrieve your data

Comment: When do you want to pass the `where conference_id = ?` filter? While loading an entity or while executing a query?